# Objects - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, object

I am attempting to create an array of objects, Trees (like a forest) 12x12. They are all trees at first. The user inputs the number of fires to start and the probability of the fires spreading to one of the surrounding objects.  I have it working when I use an array[][] but when trying to make it work with objects I cannot get the objects to check their surrounding objects then decide to catch fire or not. I am new to the site so I am unsure exactly what you need to see.

```
public static void fireCheck(Tree[][] trees1){

    int i = 0;
    int c = 0;

    for(i = 0; i <= 11; i ++) {

        for(c = 0; c <= 11; c ++) {

            switch(trees1[i][c].getStatus()){

                case '^': break;
                case '.': break;
                case '*': trees1[i][c].burned(); break;
                default: break;
            }

            if(trees1[i][c].getStatus() == '^'){

                if(i <= 10){

                    switch(trees1[i + 1][c].getStatus()){

                            case '^': break;
                            case '.': break;
                            case '*': trees1[i+1][c].probability(); break;
                            default: break;
                    }

                    if(c <= 10){
                        switch(trees1[i][c + 1].getStatus()){

                            case '^': break;
                            case '.': break;
                            case '*': trees1[i][c+1].probability(); break;
                            default: break;
                        }

                        switch(trees1[i + 1][c + 1].getStatus()){

                            case '^': break;
                            case '.': break;
                            case '*': trees1[i+1][c+1].probability(); break;
                            default: break;
                        }


                    }
                }

                if(i >= 1){

                    switch(trees1[i - 1][c].getStatus()){

                            case '^': break;
                            case '.': break;
                            case '*': trees1[i-1][c].probability(); break;
                            default: break;
                        }

                    if(c >= 1){
                        switch(trees1[i][c - 1].getStatus()){

                            case '^': break;
                            case '.': break;
                            case '*': trees1[i][c-1].probability(); break;
                            default: break;
                        }

                        switch(trees1[i - 1][c - 1].getStatus()){

                            case '^': break;
                            case '.': break;
                            case '*': trees1[i-1][c-1].probability(); break;
                            default: break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(i <= 10){

                    if(c >= 1){

                        switch(trees1[i+1][c-1].getStatus()){

                            case '^': break;
                            case '.': break;
                            case '*': trees1[i+1][c-1].probability(); break;
                            default: break;

                        }
                    }
                }               
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This looks like C or Java code you should tag your questions with the programming language to get the right peoples attention for your question.

Comment: great advise, I will do this.

Comment: "I have it working when I use an array[][]" what is the type of array here? And what is your problem in using an array of objects

Comment: array of characters was the original. I am not 100% sure of my problem with my array of object other than I can change the symbols of the object but I cannot get it to check and compare itself to the surrounding objects then change accordingly. If an object that surrounds it is on fire, the fire can spread.

Comment: What happens when you run this? What exactly isn't working?

Comment: If you were using a char[][]..put up here what you were doing with it and your tree class..then ask which part are you actually asking?

Comment: Is the `getStatus()` returning correct character, and is the `probability()` and `burnt()` method setting the correct character for status?

Comment: yes when I do a system.out.println of the getstatus() it provides a character.

Comment: I will double check the other methods. Is there a way to post more code to see on this same post? Sorry I am new here.

Comment: "Is the getStatus() returning correct character" - yes when I do a test it shows the correct symbol (original symbol I have it enter) "probability() and burnt()" Burnt simply changes the char variable to a '.' , I know that works since when the tree is originaly lit on fire it changes it to a '.' when ran. Probability is possibly the problem, I will see if I can add what the probability code does, if I can figure that out. Thanks for the feedback, it helps to have placed to even start checking.

Comment: Forgot to update this. I fixed the problem after looking at the silly logic I was using. I was having object[i][c] look around it but as you can see my command to change it was the same object it was supposed to be looking at ie i look to object[i+1][c+1] then had the command to change that one, so of course it would not work. If object is this, change it to this. So only if it was already '*' would it "change it" to '*'. .. wow. Thanks for the feedback as everything helps me learn. Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to make this program more object oriented.

Create a class Tree, which has some position and a way of identifying if another tree is neighbor.

```
interface OurTree{
    public int getPosition();
    public boolean isNeighbour(OurTree tree);
    public boolean isBurning();
}
```

Implementing above interface will help you.

Create a set of objects of the above implemented interface (assume this as forest). Loop through the set, and identify if any tree is on fire. if yes, burn its neighbours.

Alternatively you can define a method to return neighbours of given tree, and burn them all at once.